# equation of droplet falling down versus time

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

A droplet of water is falling down in a stationary gaseous phase. Suppose that the shape of my droplet is consistent, I want to find the equation of falling the droplet versus time.

Comment: -1. Unclear. There are many assumptions which could be made about the forces on the drop, depending on its size. Also the possibility of it evaporating or absorbing moisture from the ambient gaseous phase. And what does *consistent shape* mean?

Answer (score 2):

To solve your problem you just need to use the Newton's second law. First you want to know all the forces implicated in the problem and then you can obtain the acceleration of the droplet.

Because of the gravitational field of the Earth, the droplet will fall with constant acceleration $g=9.8 m/s^{2}$ so in the equation you will have a constant term. Then you can solve the problem only with those suppositions:

$m·\ddot x=m·g$

So the acceleration is just the gravity and you have a second order differential equation which solution is:

$x(t)=x(0)+\dot x(0)·t+\frac{g·t^2}{2}$

But that problem is so easy so we can complicate it more adding a viscosity $\eta$ to the environment.We have to suppose also that the droplet is spherical so we will have a Stokes coefficient $k=6·\pi·r$ where r is the radius of the droplet. In this case The droplet suffers a force because of friction with the environment like a droplet in a cloud in a rainy day.
The equation in this case is:

$m·\ddot x=-k·\eta·\dot x+m·g$

And we have another second order differential equation which we can solve:

$x(t)=x(0)+[\frac{mg}{k\eta}-\dot x(0)]·\frac{m}{k\eta}·(e^{-\frac{k\eta t}{m}}-1)+\frac{mg}{k\eta}·t$

Where $x(0)$ is the initial position and $\dot x(0)$ is the initial velocity.